# Is it possible to have triangle other than equilateral of which sum of two sides = twice the other side?

Tags: geometry

Please help.

Is it possible to have triangle other than equilateral of which sum of two sides = twice the other side?

That means is it possible to have $b+c=2a$, if $\triangle ABC$ is not an equilateral triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; why not? It obviously doesn’t happen in your picture, but what’s to keep you from having a triangle with sides $3,4$, and $5$, with $a=4$?

Comment: @Sumit: You’re very welcome.